# hololens 101 chapter 3: what is "=>" for?

Tags: c#, lambda, hololens-emulator

[Hololense tutorial here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_101e#Chapter_3_-_Gestures)

in chapter 3 GazeGestureManager.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.VR.WSA.Input;

public class GazeGestureManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GazeGestureManager Instance { get; private set; }

    // Represents the hologram that is currently being gazed at.
    public GameObject FocusedObject { get; private set; }

    GestureRecognizer recognizer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Instance = this;

        // Set up a GestureRecognizer to detect Select gestures.
        recognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
        recognizer.TappedEvent += (source, tapCount, ray) =>
        {
            // Send an OnSelect message to the focused object and its ancestors.
            if (FocusedObject != null)
            {
                FocusedObject.SendMessageUpwards("OnSelect");
            }
        };
        recognizer.StartCapturingGestures();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Figure out which hologram is focused this frame.
        GameObject oldFocusObject = FocusedObject;

        // Do a raycast into the world based on the user's
        // head position and orientation.
        var headPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
        var gazeDirection = Camera.main.transform.forward;

        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(headPosition, gazeDirection, out hitInfo))
        {
            // If the raycast hit a hologram, use that as the focused object.
            FocusedObject = hitInfo.collider.gameObject;
        }
        else
        {
            // If the raycast did not hit a hologram, clear the focused object.
            FocusedObject = null;
        }

        // If the focused object changed this frame,
        // start detecting fresh gestures again.
        if (FocusedObject != oldFocusObject)
        {
            recognizer.CancelGestures();
            recognizer.StartCapturingGestures();
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't understand this line:

```
recognizer.TappedEvent += (source, tapCount, ray) =>
```

What is inside `()`, why there is a `=>` operator and what is for?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at C# Lambda operator [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx). It separates the block from the input variables on the left. So it looks like that the block will be executed on the tapped event and the parameters (source, tapCount, ray) will be passed and can be used in the block.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of it as a "inlined delegate to handle events or callbacks". Hope that helps :)